# Display a custom string of enum status in a pie chart Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, pie-chart, chartkick

I'm using Chartkick Gem to display a pie chart about medications' statuses. The status its a enum field like the following

```
enum status: { good: 0, near_expiry: 1, expired: 2}
```

Currently im showing the next pie chart:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7bfe.png

Behind the graphic:

```
 <%= pie_chart @medications.group(:status).count %>
```

I want to display the statuses name with space instead of before defined in the dictionary. For example, "Good", "Near Expiry", "Expired". It is possible? How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in a Rails project, you could use [`Hash#transform_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys):

```
{"good" => 0, "near_expiry"=>1, "expired"=>2}.transform_keys do |key| 
  key.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
=> {"Good"=>0, "Near Expiry"=>1, "Expired"=>2}
```